# From an inequality for the Euler's totient function to a combination of Firoozbakht's conjecture and Nicolas' criterion for the Riemann hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, inequalities, asymptotics

In this post we ask about the veracity of an inequality deduced from a combination of Firoozbakht's conjecture (see [1] or [2]) and Nicolas' criterion for the Riemann hypothesis (see for instance [3]). The inequality was easily deduced, and I don't know if it is in the literature.

For integers $m\geq 1$ we denote the $m$-th prime number as $p_m$ and the primorial of order $m$ as $N_m=\prod_{j=1}^m p_j$.

From a standard inequality for the Euler's totient function $\varphi(x)$ (see the last paragraph in the answer of the [**MSE 3275096** question *Does entropy increase when multiplying two numbers?*,  June 2019](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275096/does-entropy-increase-when-multiplying-two-numbers)) one has the following easy deduction.

**Claim 1 (Edited, see comments).** *One has* $\forall k\geq 1$ *integer and*  $\forall n\geq 1$ *integer that the inequality* $$p_{n+1}\varphi(N_k)\geq \varphi(p_{n+1}N_k)\tag{1}$$ *holds.*

Thus multiplying the inequality $(1)$ by the primorial, and taking the reciprocals of each side of the inequality one gets the inequality of the following claim.

**Claim 2 (Edited, see comments) .** *For intgers* $k\geq 1$ *and* $n\geq 1$ *the inequality* $$\frac{N_k}{\varphi(N_k)}\leq\frac{N_k}{\varphi(p_{n+1}N_k)}p_{n+1}\tag{2}$$ *holds.*

Now the idea was to combine the RHS of $(2)$ with Firoozbakht's conjecture, while one combines the LHS of $(2)$ using Nicolas' criterion for the Riemann hypothesis. We get the following statement that thus is a statement that I don't know if is true o false (one can to check it, using an approximation for the Euler-Mascheroni constant, for small segments of integers  using a Pari/GP program, I did it). This is next statement which title is *Statement (?)*, because is the question of this post.

**Statement (?).** *The inequality* $$e^{\gamma}\log\log N_k<\frac{N_k}{\varphi(p_{n+1}N_k)}p_{n}^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\tag{3}$$

*holds* $\forall k\geq 1$ *integer and* $\forall n\geq 1$ *integer.*

> **Question.** I would like to know if it is possible to prove that the inequality $(3)$ from previous statement is true $\forall n\geq 1$ and $\forall k\geq 1$ integers, or well if you can to find a counterexample showing that $(3)$ is false. **Many thanks.**

If my question has a good mathematical content and you can to add heuristic about the answer (the veracity of Statement (?)) then feel free to do it. As secondary question (**added**) if you can to find easily a counterexample, feel free to discuss if there could be integer numbers $n_0>1$ and $k_0>1$ for which the inequality $(3)$ holds for all $n\geq n_0$ and for all $k\geq k_0$. I don't know if other combinations of the Firoozbakht's conjecture and the Riemann's hypothesis are feasibles.

**Computational evidence (Added).** The *Statement (?)* is true for all integers $1\leq n\leq 400$ and for all integers $1\leq k\leq 400$ as you can to see  evaluating the line written in Pari/GP (PARI/GP Development Headquarters)

`for(n=1, 400, for(k=1, 400, if((exp(Euler))*log(log(prod(t=1, k, prime(t))))>(prod(t=1, k, prime(t))/eulerphi(prime(n+1)*prod(t=1, k, prime(t))))*prime(n)^(1+1/n),print(n," ",k))))`

that doesn't show counterexamples as outputs in this evaluation (it takes a minute), from the web *Sage Cell Server* choosing as language *GP*.

**Remark.** If I'm right a similar statement-conjecture is feasible for a similar combination for Firoozbakht Conjecture and Robin's criterion, exploiting the fact that $$\sigma(nm)>m\sigma(n)$$
that holds for integers $n\geq 1$ and $m>1$, where $\sigma(x)$ denotes the sum of divisors function.

### References:

[1] The article [*Firoozbakht's conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture) from Wikipedia.

[2] *Conjecture 30. The Firoozbakht Conjecture*, from Carlos Rivera's The Prime Puzzles & Problems Connection, (August 2012).

[3] Jean L. Nicolas, *Petites valeurs de la fonction d’Euler*, J. Number Theory **17** (1983), 375–388.

Comment: As it was said I don't know if my combination as *Statement (?)* has a good mathematical content or if it is interesting. Feel free to add feedback/critics about it.

Comment: 3 times phi(6) equals phi(3*6), so the first two claims do not hold. I suspect that your Statement also does not hold.  Gerhard "Perhaps Edit Post For Brevity" Paseman, 2019.10.26.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I think that it works now, many thanks for your useful comment. I've edited the **Claim 1** and **Claim** 2 In recent past hours I wrote a little program written in Pari/GP to test the first cases of Statement, thus if you want I can provide it.

Comment: (1/2) If you search in Internet the web *Sage Cell Server*, you can to run the following code (it is a line written in Pari/GP) `for(n=1, 100, for(k=1, 100, if((exp(0.577215664))*log(log(prod(t=1, k, prime(t))))>(prod(t=1, k, prime(t))/eulerphi(prime(n+1)*prod(t=1, k, prime(t))))*prime(n)^(1+1/n),print(n))))` you need to paste the code and evaluate it choosing *GP* as language. You can verify that also for the identity (the code is using the string `==` instead of the inequality) doesn't provide outputs.

Comment: (2/2) Thus (while this isn't a proof since I've used an approximation of the Euler-Mascheroni constant) there should be no small counterexamples to inequality in **Statement.** Many thanks again @GerhardPaseman Now the inequlities in Claim 1 and 2 should be rights. Thus I am asking for a proof, critic or counterexample for **Statement.**

Comment: Please it is also welcome feedback in comments from professors or professional mathematicians here about if the question is interesting. Feel free to refer to colleagues of your university or job this or other of my posts, if you think that for your colleagues can be interesting read or study these my questions. Many thanks and good day.